# How to have form within email Laravel?

Tags: laravel, forms, email

I would like to figure out how to create an email that allows users to choose a response to the email and return it to my Laravel application. This seems to be a very common piece of email today, but I can't figure out how to do it in my Laravel project. Here is the code I have tried for the email markdown:

```
@component('mail::message')

// greeting stuff

<form method="POST" action="/mailresponse" class="form-signin">

{{ csrf_field() }}

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://mysite.dev/mailresponse', 'value' => 'yes', 'name' => 'response'])
Yes
@endcomponent

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://mysite.dev/mailresponse', 'value' => 'no', 'name' => 'response'])
No
@endcomponent

</form>

@endcomponent
```

I ask a simple yes/no question in the email, and would like to be able to track the response from each user. Here is the controller I created to attempt to handle this:

```
class ResponseController extends Controller
{
     public function response() 
     {

    $data = request(['response']);

    return view('response.email');
    }
}
```

I am aware I am not doing anything with the data just yet, because I am simply just trying to figure out how to get the data to be there. And I have also set up a route:

```
Route::post('/mailresponse', 'ResponseController@response');
```

But, when I try to click on one of the responses, I get an error at the `/mailresponse` url of `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message`

How would I get this to function properly? I am thinking that it is something wrong with the implementation of the `mail::button` components but am not sure how to structure them within the framework.

Comment: Instead of passing the value with a form, why don't you pass it with the url?

Comment: How could I achieve that?

Comment: Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#urls-for-controller-actions) out. You can create multiple urls for multiple buttons e.g. One url for "Accept" and another for "Decline".

Comment: I can't figure out how to make this work. I want to associate each url with a particular user, but I can't seem to pass through my user variable to the notification view in the same way I can to a mail view.

Comment: Notification View? I thought you are asking about email

Comment: Notifications can be emails. I am sending an email via notification. I got it to work by changing a little bit of source code to allow me to create a second action in the `toMail` function of the notification, thereby allowing me to pass through all the data to the controller

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant pop-up notification. How do you pass your user variable?

Comment: Everything (user and other data) is being passed through the constructor of the `notification`, so the controller also accepts that data

Comment: Can you show the code?